# Jinja extends, pushing content from child back to parent

Tags: python, jinja2

I want to have a base template and child template that both extend blocks in both directions (between each other) is this possible?

base.html

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>

<body class="">

    <div>
        {% block header_items %}{% endblock %}
    </div>


    <div style="min-height:90vh">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and then a child template

child.html

```html
{% extends "schedule_layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h3>CONTENT</h3>
{% endblock %}
```

Is it possible to, from the child, push content into the "header_items" block in the base.html template. Bearing in mind I have multiple child templates all representing different pages on my site.

Any suggestions?

I can't also extend the main template in the child as then they both will be constant referencing each other.

Comment: I don't understand problem - can't you  use `{% block header_items %}` inside `child`? Maybe you should show what you have in `schedule_layout.html`. OR even better - create minimal working code which we could simply copy and run to see problem. And if you get error then show FULL error message in question (not in comments) as text. We can't run your code and we can't read in your mind - you have to describe all details in question.

Comment: I apologise I thought I was clear, obviously not enough for many on here. As I'm sure you are aware it's tough to structure a question when you do not understand how to ask it and what options are available to you.

Comment: You have however seems to make work out that `extends` appears to be able to handle multiple blocks and exactly what I needed, I've managed to answer my own question. I just didn't realise

Answer (score 0):

I realise that some people may not even understand my question but i've managed to find out the answer I need.

The `extends` in the child template is able to handle mutiple blocks and it just didn't cross my mind. So to add content into the `base.html` in both blocks you just need them both in the child template also.

child.html

```html
{% extends "schedule_layout.html" %}

{% block header_items %}add me to the base {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h3>CONTENT</h3>
{% endblock %}
```

Of course you do !!